# SQL line on mysql gives syntax error

Tags: mysql

Please tell me what was wrong with this line and any suggestions:

```
ALTER TABLE iv_customer_token CHANGE customer_id customer_id INT(10) NOT NULL UNSIGNED;
```

Error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED' at line 1

Comment: What's the syntax error? This doesn't look like an invalid query...

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED' at line 1

Comment: Can you try to replicate the same error on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: What the error says: `UNSIGNED` does not belong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNSIGNED` needs to be after the data define type.

so

```
ALTER TABLE iv_customer_token CHANGE customer_id customer_id INT(10) NOT NULL UNSIGNED;
```

needs to be

```
ALTER TABLE iv_customer_token CHANGE customer_id customer_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE iv_customer_token MODIFY customer_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```